# Programatically add text field to Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to add a text field to all my forms programatically. There is a hook for adding hidden fields (wpcf7_form_hidden_fields) but I can not find one for regular fields. I tried modifying the form via wpcf7_form_elements which works, I get my new field. However it is not really part of the Contact Form 7 cosmos, I can not use wpcf7 validation on it.

Is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Try: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you trying to add a field programmatically?